# DialogLauncher Click Action

Tags: c#, vsto

I want my dialog launcher to spawn a windows form I created.  Problem is when I use these event handlers it doesn't work.

```
    private void ribbonDialogLauncherImpl1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void group1_DialogLauncherClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
```

Neither work.  And ribbonDialogLauncherImpl1 is the name of the dialog launcher as it was instantiated in the designer.  I don't understand why the click event won't bring up my forms.  I even tried with just messageboxes and console output, the event doesn't appear to fire at all.  Where do I register the event or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going to the events tab of the properties section with group selected I could set an event handler.